# Convert JSON datatype to Python datatype - user selects the JSON data type

Tags: python, json, type-conversion, user-controls, user-input

I have a use case where I am reading some data from an API call, but need to transform the data from the database into the user's chosen data type format. he conversion needs to happen in Python before sending back to user.

Json data type can be: String, Number

example:

```
input_dict: {"parameters": {"price": "STRING", "item": "NUMBER"}}
input_list : [{"price": 1, "item": 1}, {"price": 8.99, "item": 2, {"price": 9.99, "item": 3}] <- price and item are integers


Output_result : [{"price": "1", "item": 1}, {"price": "8.99", "item": 2, {"price": "9.99", "item": 3}] <-price converted to string as per user requirement and item stayed as is
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner solution, using a small mapping dictionary to translate the values into corresponding python classes. Beware that you will need to use float() if provided number are not integers.

```
input_dict = {"parameters": {"price": "STRING", "item": "NUMBER"}}
input_list = [{"price": 1, "item": 1}, {"price": 8.99, "item": 2}, {"price": 9.99, "item": 3}] 

mapping = { "STRING" : str,
            "NUMBER": int}

output_list = [{ key: mapping[input_dict['parameters'][key]](value) for (key, value) in e.items()} for e in input_list ]

print(output_list)
# => [{'price': '1', 'item': 1}, {'price': '8.99', 'item': 2}, {'price': '9.99', 'item': 3}]
```

Comment: problem is if string is "8.99" it converts to 8 when user asks to convert string to number

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment. The code produces the output you specified. like I said, if you want to handle floating point numbers, you will need to use "float" instead of "int" in the mapping

Comment: input_dict = {"parameters": {"price": "STRING", "item": "NUMBER"}}
input_list =[{'price': '1', 'item': 1}, {'price': '8.99', 'item': 2}, {'price': '9.99', 'item': 3}]

Comment: sorry but it's still not clear. Your input_list in the comment now includes quotes like the output_result of the question, so I don't understand what you need to convert. Please edit your question to specify exactly what are the inputs and what is the expected output.